# Page redirects to login page

Tags: asp.net, redirect, sql-server-2012, iis-8

i have a web application when we click first time on any page it redirect to the log in page, 
when i log in again i can access the page and it works fine it is only giving error when i'm hosting it on IIS

I'm using

- iis 8
- asp.net 4.0
- OS: sql server 2012
- browser: IE10

im using form authentication 
the user can see the login page before login 
and once he logs in and tries to go the next page he is redirected to the login page again again he enter the credentials the page works fine 
but when i restart the server the error cones again

web key

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
<sessionState timeout="180" />
```

Comment: what it gives error can u include in this quistion?

Comment: it ask for login credentials if i enter the credentials it will work fine till the the server is restarted

Comment: Please provide more details. Are you using form authentication? The page which redirects you to login page can be seen before login or not etc... Also provide you web.config file setting related to the problem.

Comment: Set default and login page in your form authentication on webconfiq

Comment: my default is login page

Answer (score 0):

If your login page redirecting again you have to set the login session according to that in this code the timeout value is set so that it will not redirect again after login so try this code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "TimeoutScript", 
"setTimeout(""top.location.href = '~/Login.aspx'""," &
 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SessionTimeoutMilliseconds") & ");", True)
```

Comment: i have give the SessionTimeoutMilliseconds for 3 hrs

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on in your question, but the authentication carrier is probably the cause. are you using cookies or session information that is set to a different server or path?

Comment: i'm using both
if he click save password then cookie is created else session is created